# Merging two sorted lists into one in descending order

Tags: python, recursion, merge

I've been able to figure out how to merge two sorted lists in ascending order, but I'm having trouble finding a way to do so in the opposite direction. How can I merge the two lists into one in descending order without reversing the string after?

Comment: What happens if you change `>` to `<=`?

Comment: Justo to confirm:`lst1` and `lst2` are both sorted in ascending order, right?

Comment: Remember that you need to use the same function to accomplish the recursion, i.e., also use `merge` function instead of a second function `merge_recur`

Comment: The <= didn't seem to work for sorting the list in reverse order. Yes, lst1 and lst2 are both sorted in ascending order. I updated the code so that the function is named correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do everything in the opposite way--retrieve items from the tail instead of the head, go for the larger of the two when making comparisons, and return the remaining list in reverse order when the other is exhausted:

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):
    if not lst1:
        return lst2[::-1]
    if not lst2:
        return lst1[::-1]
    if lst1[-1] < lst2[-1]:
        return [lst2[-1]] + merge(lst1, lst2[:-1])
    else:
        return [lst1[-1]] + merge(lst1[:-1], lst2)
```

so that:

```
 merge([2,5,9,12], [0,1,3,4,8])
```

would return:

```
 [12, 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without recursion?

Comment: You can post this as a separate question since it is quite different to the question here in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, is there a way to do this without using [::-1], since that is just reversing the string?

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't want use to use `[::-1]`, you can reverse the list yourself by using a loop to iterate through the list item by item from the tail, and append the item to a new list. It's important that you return the remaining list in reverse order, since you want the output to be in descending order but your input lists are in ascending order.

Comment: You can also use the `reversed` built-in.