# Merge two sorted lists into one without recursion

Tags: python, merge

I have been able to merge two sorted lists into one, but I'm not completely sure how I would merge them into one list that is in descending order without recursion.

Comment: What is the relevance of the listed code?

Comment: The code I wrote merges two lists into one that's in ascending order. I'm trying to figure out a way to do so in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why not just iterate the other direction?

Answer (score 2):

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):

    if not lst1:
        return [lst2[idx] for idx in range(len(lst2)-1, -1, -1)] # lst2[::-1]
    if not lst2:
        return [lst1[idx] for idx in range(len(lst1)-1, -1, -1)] # lst1[::-1]

    merged_lst = []

    i,j = len(lst1)-1 ,len(lst2)-1 

    while i > -1 and j > -1:
        if lst1[i] > lst2[j]:
            merged_lst.append(lst1[i])
            i -=1

        elif lst1[i] < lst2[j]:
            merged_lst.append(lst2[j])
            j -=1

        else:
            merged_lst.extend( [lst1[i],lst2[j]] ) 
            i -=1
            j -=1

    if i > -1:
        merged_lst.extend( lst1[idx] for idx in range(i,-1,-1))
        # or merged_lst.extend( lst1[:i+1][::-1])
    else:
        merged_lst.extend( lst2[idx] for idx in range(j,-1,-1)) 
        # or merged_lst.extend( lst2[:j+1][::-1])

    return merged_lst
```

#### *explanation*:

*helper functions*

```
def reverse_lst( lst):
    return [lst[idx] for idx in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1)]


# if you don't even want to use list comprehension 
def basic_reverse_lst( lst):
    rev_lst = []

    # start( inclusive), stop( exclusive), step
    for idx in range(len(lst)-1 , -1, -1):
        rev_lst.append( lst[idx])

    return rev_lst
```

*merge function*

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):
    # assuming lst1 and lst2 are sorted list(ascending order)
```

*empty list case ( I will refer to this later)*

```
    if not lst1:
        # since lst1 is empty our merge list will only contain elements of lst2

        return basic_reverse_lst(lst2) # if you don't want to use lst2[::-1] and list comprehension
    if not lst2:
        return reverse_lst(lst1)
```

*merged_lst will eventually be returned by merge function it will contain our final answer ( descending order)*

```
    merged_lst = []
```

*i* and *j* are initialized with last index of lst1 and lst2 respectively because we will be traversing the list in reverse ie from biggest element of list to smallest.

```
    # last_idx = len(lst) -1 
    i,j = len(lst1)-1 ,len(lst2)-1
```

Understanding how `i` and `j` are being decremented is crucial

Imagine two arrows one which points to element at index i of lst1  and another to element at index j of lst2 keep moving this arrows as value of i and j changes.

run while loop until one of the list gets exhausted ie until we have not gone through at least one of the list completely which implies after some time at least one of the arrow will be pointing to the element at index 0 and in the end it will be pointing to -1 ( in python its the last element of list but we treat it as index out of bound situation or here simply it means we have completely traversed this list).

```
    while i > -1 and j > -1:
        if lst1[i] > lst2[j]:
            merged_lst.append(lst1[i])
            i -=1

        elif lst1[i] < lst2[j]:
            merged_lst.append(lst2[j])
            j -=1

        else:
            merged_lst.extend( [lst1[i],lst2[j]] ) 

            i -=1
            j -=1

            '''
            # you can use extend( some_sequence) or do append()
            # here it depends what you want since you have not mentioned in your question exactly
            # what kind of behaviour you want when elements of two list are same I presumed that you want to add both of them in merged list

            merged_lst.append(lst1[i])
            merged_lst.append(lst2[j])
            '''
```

extract rest of elements in reverse order from the list which we have not completely gone through, this become just same as our starting case when one of the list passed to our func merge(lst1, lst2) was empty so all we need to do is reverse the non-empty list( one which we have not completely traversed yet).

```
    if i > -1:
        # lst1 is not completely traversed yet

        # merged_lst.extend( lst1[idx] for idx in range(i,-1,-1)) or # lst1[:i+1][::-1]

        rest = lst1[:i+1] # rest contains elements of lst1 which we have not seen in while loop
        merged_lst.extend( reverse_lst(rest))

    else:
        # lst2 is not completely traversed yet
        # you can extract then reverse like we are doing in above if condition or you can simply do it in one line

        merged_lst.extend( lst2[idx] for idx in range(j,-1,-1))  # or lst2[:j+1][::-1]

    return merged_lst


print(merge([1,2,23,42],[])) # [42, 23, 2, 1]

print(merge([1,2,23,42], [5,7,11,19,21])) # [42, 23, 21, 19, 11, 7, 5, 2, 1]

print(merge([1,21,23,42], [5,7,11,19,21,97])) # [97, 42, 23, 21, 21, 19, 11, 7, 5, 1]

print(merge([1,19,19,21,21,23,42], [5,7,11,19,21,21,97])) # [97, 42, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21, 19, 19, 19, 11, 7, 5, 1]
```

Comment: @John Wahlberg  before you posted this question I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528449/merging-two-sorted-lists-into-one-in-descending-order)

Comment: How would this be done without using [::-1]? This question (as opposed to the other) is about merging two lists without using recursion.

Comment: @JohnWahlberg see comments you can use list comprehension or good old for loop

Comment: @JohnWahlberg just play with the code I have sprinkled alternatives as comments just uncomment them and remove the appropriate code

Comment: @Tanmayjain, what is meant by see comments?

Comment: @StephenRauch sorry for confusion, which are in code.

Comment: So code dumps are rarely good answers.  Good answers explain.  [Some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aanswer&mixed=0)

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you for suggestion I will try to improve my answer by adding some explanation.